# Split a string, eval the parts and rejoin

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to split a string by a single character and use the javascript `eval()` and then rejoin the string.

So I have a string that looks like this 2*2d8/2d8, I split the string by the `/` like below

```
remDice.split("/").forEach(function (remDie) {
    console.log(remDie);
});
```

This gives me the two different parts, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the next part which is split by the character `d` and then `eval()` the two parts. So that my final string would look something like `4d8/2d8`.

I am aware that you should avoid `eval()` but that really isn't a concern with this project.

Comment: What result are you expecting from this calculation?  Within your callback for the `.forEach()` you could always do another `.split()` call. Is this limited to one level of this type of input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution:

```js
var str = '2*2d8/2d8',
    str2 = str.split('/').map(v => v.split('d').map(c => eval(c)).join('d')).join('/');
    
    console.log(str2);
```

Comment: I still want to `d` character, I want the math operation to only happen to the left and right side of the `d` so that the `2*2` becomes `4`. The final string should look like `4d8/2d8`.

Sorry I am not sure I worded that very well.

Answer (score 1):

Update of @Kind user's solution because I think original Q expected a bit different result.

```js
var str = '2*2d8/2d8',
    str2 = str.split('/').map(v => {
        s = v.split('d')
        return eval(s[0]) + 'd' + eval(s[1])
    }).join('/')
    
    console.log(str2);
```

Comment: This is what I was expecting. Wow that was amazing!